# Default navigation back button not displayed in SwiftUI view when navigating from UIKit view

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am trying to setup the default navigation between views, I am able to open my swiftUIview from my uikit view controller but not go back. I looked at a youtube video where they have practically the same code for navigation yet his code displays a back button and mines does not. For reference here is what my SwiftUIView looks like when I navigate to it from my UIKit view controller.
[image: SwiftUIView current]

[image: SwiftUI back button expected]

In my UIKit file I have

```
    let swiftUIcontoller = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(swiftUIcontoller, animated: true)
```

In my SwiftUI file I have

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution for this, because I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @MuhammadDanishQureshi Yea turns out one of the members in my team had .setNavigationBarHidden to true in UIKIt so I just changed it to false after pushViewController. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Within SwiftUI view it will show automatic if you use `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink`. But if you are navigating from a UIKit view to a SwiftUI view, the default navigation back button might not be automatically displayed.

You can try like below:

1. In SwiftUI content use `NavigationView`
2. In UIKit ViewController

   ```swift
   @IBAction func navigateToSwiftUIView() {
       let swiftUIView = SwiftUIView()
       swiftUIView.presentationMode = .fullScreen
       navigationController?.pushViewController(swiftUIView, animated: true)
   }
   ```

Comment: .presentationMode is a get only property and this did not work

Comment: 1. Would you please check skipping swiftUIView.presentationMode = .fullScreen line. Back button appear or not.

Comment: 2. Use NavigationView on SwiftUI content

Comment: @Md.MominulIslam both of your suggestions are not working. I skipped that .fullScreen and already embed the SwiftUI View body in NavigationView.